# jQuery calculates separate lines, then grand total - live

Tags: jquery

building a calculator and don't really know where to begin.

I have a calculator that has several rows - item, item cost, an input for quantity and then the total for that item. The user will input the quantity for **some** of the items. The calculator will need to display the cost per item live (without a button), and then all of the totals will need to add and calculate the grand total (displays at the bottom).

```
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-body">
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 1</div>
        <div class="table-cell">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 2</div>
        <div class="table-cell">$20</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 3</div>
        <div class="table-cell">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 4</div>
        <div class="table-cell">$30</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 5</div>
        <div class="table-cell">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row footer">
        <div class="table-cell">Total</div>
        <div class="table-cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="table-cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="table-cell">= $10,000 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have included a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xgL4q8w6/

Any suggestions as to how I should approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: Look into running a function with [`.keyup()`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another column called `<div class="table-cell result"></div>`

Then I added a class for the total called `.sum`

I also added a data attribute to the row with the cost of an item, like this:

`<div class="table-cell" data-value="25">$25</div>`

Then I added an event listener that will act when user presses on a key in the keyboard.

**See demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $("input:text").on("keyup", function() {
    var rowEl = $(this).closest(".table-row");
    var inputStr = $(this).val();
    var multiplier = rowEl.find("[data-value]").data('value');
    var sum = 0;

    rowEl.find('.result').html(parseInt(inputStr * multiplier) || '?');

    $('.result').each(function (index, element) {
        //console.log($(element).html());
        sum += parseInt($(element).html()) || 0;
    });

    $(".footer .sum").html("$" + sum);
  });
});
```

```css
.calculator .table {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.calculator .table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.calculator .table-row.bottom .table-cell {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.calculator .table-row.footer {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.calculator .table-row.footer .table-cell {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
}

.calculator .table-heading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.calculator .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.calculator .table-cell input {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.calculator .table-cell:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.calculator .table-body {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.result {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-body">
      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 1</div>
        <div class="table-cell" data-value="25">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
        <div class="table-cell result"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 2</div>
        <div class="table-cell" data-value="20">$20</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
        <div class="table-cell result"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 3</div>
        <div class="table-cell" data-value="25">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
        <div class="table-cell result"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 4</div>
        <div class="table-cell" data-value="30">$30</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
        <div class="table-cell result"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">Item 5</div>
        <div class="table-cell" data-value="25">$25</div>
        <div class="table-cell">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="-">
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">= </div>
        <div class="table-cell result"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="table-row footer">
        <div class="table-cell">Total</div>
        <div class="table-cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="table-cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="table-cell sum">= $10,000 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After fully fleshing out lloyd's idea of `onKeyUp` and forking your fiddle, I came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/eqwert/tospqvx6/

Its only reliant on the order of the columns and also assumes that the "cost" column values are preceded with a `$`

```
$(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
    var cost = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().children().eq(1).text().substring(1));
    $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(3).text(cost * $(this).val());

    var total = 0;
    ($( ".table-row" ).not(".footer")).each(function() {
      let add = parseInt($(this).children().eq(3).text());
      total += (add) ? add : 0;
    });

    $( ".table-row.footer" ).children().eq(3).text("= $" + total);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `.keyup()`

Give all your input a class such as `class="CalcItem"` in my example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control CalcItem" id="Item1" placeholder="-">
```

Trigger event like so

```
$(".CalcItem").keyup(function(){
    var totalCost = 0;
    totalCost += $("#Item1").val() * 25;

    // totalCost += all your other values

    document.getElementById("Total").textContent = "$" + totalCost;
})
```